# Paging app for teams

Tags: ios, communication

I need an iOS (Android would be a bonus) application that allows me to send "jobs" out to my team members in which they can respond to. 
It’s like a paging app, where I can ask for help on a job and team members can reply if they’re available.

Preferably I would like a free solution that relies on the cloud so I can send out pager messages. If this isn’t possible please still leave some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Is something like "OnPage" what you're looking for?
If you don't know what that is, it is an incident alert management platform/app that allows you to send out alerts, incidents and services to a group of people with a lot of functional features.

OnPage is free to download and is a quarterly/yearly subscription fee after a 7-day trial.

[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onpage&hl=pt_PT)

[iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/onpage/id427935899)